# VBA Macro to Remove Only Numbers from All the Tables in File.

Tags: vba

I would to like to get help in VBA (In MS WORD) , If some body tells me how to create a macro that just removes numbers from all the cells of Tables, but leaves those numbers that are with Text (like gh4).

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just record the macro in Word. Use wildcard search and replace. Search for <[0-9]@> and replace with nothing.